# swift insert row with animation effect

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

In the first draft of my app, I filled my NSTableView with a static array.
I had a NSButton, which inserts a new row with an animation effect like this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: tableview.numberOfRows), withAnimation: .effectFade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Short question at this point:
Do I need the begin-/endUpdates() command?
I see now difference if I use this code or not.

**Primary Problem:**

Now my second draft:

Now I fetch my data for the TableView from Core Data.
If I click on the NSButton (to insert a new row) I do something different: I create a new record, save it into core data, fetch all data again and reload my TableView.

This works fine, but I can't use this line anymore in my second draft.

```
tableView.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: tableview.numberOfRows), withAnimation: .effectFade)
```

Anybody an idea how can I use this "beautiful" animation with core data again?

Comment: How are you binding the data to the tableview?

Comment: not with cocoa binding. i use the tableview functions

Comment: You might find it easier to use Cocoa Bindings instead. Core Data is designed to be used this way. NSFetchedResultsController on iOS was developed because Cocoa Bindings don't exist on that platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short question**: You don't need `beginUpdates() / endUpdates()` for a single insert/delete/move operation, it's only needed for multiple simultaneous operations.

**Primary problem**: `reloadData()` doesn't show any animation. Instead of *...fetch all data again* and *reload my TableView* insert the object in the table view with `insertRows(at`. It updates the table view showing the animation.